# Installation of Ubuntu Which version do I use on my Net book?

Tags: 12.04

I have a Acer netbook with an intel atom which I have recently up graded to 2Gig of Ram.  Will the 64 bit version fo Ubuntu give me more speed and functionality or just bog it down?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Make a swap and install 64 bits , i think it will run faster.

Based on my experience , browsing  is much better using the 64bit version of Ubuntu in an Intel Atom. It is true, the 64 bit version uses more memory, but the performance is really better.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only have 2GB of RAM, I personaly don't see the need (or benefit) of running a 64Bit Version. 
If you want to save some Ressources, try Lubuntu.
I'm using Lubuntu on very old Hardware (Acer Laptop from early 2008) and it's realy fast :-)

Comment: Will Lubuntu have the same hardware support as the olain version?